# Using a script to set variables in IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-idle

Using Python 3.2 on Win7 x64. I have a script that I would like to run every time I start IDLE. This is my script:

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)

soup = BeautifulSoup()
def soupSetup(file_name, encode_type):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open("C:\\Python32\\html\\"+file_name+".html", encoding=encode_type))
```

This way everything is set and all I have to do is pass `soupSetup()` the html file I want to use and I can start working with the data.

My issue is this- if I use the code as is when I use `print(soup.prettify())`I get nothing returned but a blank line. If I don't instantiate the class first when I run the print statement I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    print(soup.prettify())
NameError: name 'soup' is not defined
```

For those not familiar with BeautifulSoup soup is an instance of `<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>`.

How can I make the soup object persist outside of my script?

Comment: Two questions in one it looks like. The first question regarding code to be executed on startup is solved by creating the modules usercustomize/sitecustomize in some directory according to http://docs.python.org/dev/library/site.html. Now the second question can be solved by augmenting `__builtin__`: `import __builtin__; setattr(__builtin__, 'soup', soup)` on the startup module and then `soup` will be magically available everywhere else. I don't recommend doing this, you might need to rethink what you want to achieve. Also, in your correct approach you will need to redefine the global `soup`.

Comment: you should put this as the answer ... since it fully answers his question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a name `soup` that is global for the module, with your statement `soup = BeautifulSoup()`. And then, in the function `soupSetup` you want to reassign the `soup` name to another `BeautifulSoup()` object, this time with data.

However: Names inside a function is local to that function and does not persist outside that function. So you end up not reassigning the global `soup` name, but creating a new separate `soup` variable inside the function, which is then deleted when the function exists. The global `soup` is not being  changed. This is why you get the empty BeatifulSoup() object you created first when you use the `soup` variable.

What you need to do is tell the function that you want to reassign the global name, like this:

```
def soupSetup(file_name, encode_type):
    global soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open("C:\\Python32\\html\\"+file_name+".html", encoding=encode_type))
```

That should do it.
Also, you don't have to set `soup = BeautifulSoup()`, it doesn't matter what you set it to as it will be overwritten by the function. Just do this instead:

```
soup = None
```

The full code should then end up as:

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)

soup = None
def soupSetup(file_name, encode_type):
    global soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open("C:\\Python32\\html\\"+file_name+".html", encoding=encode_type))
```

Comment: That really misses the point. He gets a `NameError` exception.

Comment: @mmgp: He only gets the NameError exception if he doesn't, as he say, "instantiate the class first", ie if skips the module-level `soup = BeautifulSoup()` statement. Even after re-reading I am pretty confident I have not missed any points.

Comment: I honestly think you misunderstood what he tried. He has some code that supposedly runs when he starts IDLE. Now that the code has ran, he tries to use the name `soup`, but it is nowhere to be found since it was defined solely inside that code that already ran.

Comment: @mmgp: No, that is not what he writes. You haven't not read the question carefully. He clearly states "if I use the code as is when I use print(soup.prettify())I get nothing returned but a blank line". He has access to `soup`, but it is the empty BeautifulSoup() object that he instantiates the global with.

Comment: See: "How can I make the soup object persist outside of my script?"

Comment: @mmgp: That *he* misunderstands where the problem is, is no reason for *you* to do the same. In his description it is 100% clear that the global `soup` *does* persist outside of his script. Read the question carefully. Don't just read the title and the traceback. Read *all* of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20776/discussion-between-lennart-regebro-and-mmgp)

Answer (score -1):

Two questions in one it looks like.

The first question regarding code to be executed on startup is solved by creating the modules usercustomize/sitecustomize in some directory according to http://docs.python.org/dev/library/site.html.

Now the second question can be solved by augmenting `__builtin__`:

```
import __builtin__
setattr(__builtin__, 'soup', soup)
```

on the startup module (in the appropriate place) and then soup will be magically available everywhere else. I don't recommend doing this, you might need to rethink what you want to achieve. Also, in your current approach, you redefine `soup` inside `soupSetup`. So, inside that function you need to specify that you are redefining a global variable and not creating a local one:

```
def soupSetup(...):
    global soup
    ...
```

Comment: This horrid hack may solve the problem, but it is not the correct solution in this case, as his problem is that he expects a global variable to be updated in a function, which it will not do.

Comment: Care to explain how this answer doesn't handle the update of the global variable ? The question asked indirectly for this hack, because he wants to further export the global `soup`.

Comment: He already has access to the global `soup`. "if I use the code as is when I use print(soup.prettify())I get nothing returned but a blank line." You need to re-read the question, carefully.

Comment: I would have no doubt of that if he said he wanted to persist `soup` outside of the given function, because then it is entirely different.

Comment: OK, you are new here, so I'll explain: When a newbie to Python comes in and explains what he wants to do, he is often wrong, because he is a newbie and have misunderstood something or is using the wrong terminology. This is the case here. From his description of the error it is *completely clear* that `soup` does "persist outside the script". So when he says that he wants `soup` to persist outside of the script, he has misunderstood what is happening. And since you listen to his incorrect analysis, so did you. *I* on the other hand, read his question carefully. You should to.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Are you angry just because I said your solution is the wrong one ? It seems you enjoy calling people newbie, you also said I'm one although you don't have the slightest idea of who actually I am. I'm not trying to claim I'm super-expert in Python either, but just because I'm new here too, that doesn't make me (or other people) automatically newbie in every subject in the world. Also, just because you are longer here, it doesn't automatically make you answer/understand everything correctly. It might be the case that you guessed what he wanted, or maybe not. Can we wait for him ?

Comment: I'm not angry, I'm annoyed that you don't listen but keep talking. *"It might be the case that you guessed what he wanted, or maybe not."* - Why don't you read what I write before you respond? I'm not guessing. What in this is hard to understand?

Comment: I've read your answer, it is you who are failing to read what I originally answered and insisting that your answer is correct (given the situation) above all. I don't see why you would be annoyed with me either, since I'm newbie for you and what is the point of discussing with newbies ? Right ?

Comment: My answer *is* correct. This is not an opinion or a guess, it is an objective verifiable fact. Fire up idle3 and try it for yourself. Or read the transcript of what happened when I did it: http://pastebin.com/wBRhaTa2 You do not understand what @gorideyourbike is doing, you don't understand why it doesn't work, you don't understand my solution. You could understand if you wanted to listen, but you don't. So you remain ignorant. Congratulations.

Comment: Note how your example is not consistent with the posters description of the error. You get a name error. **He does not get a name error!** You still have not actually read the question. This is what happens if you run your script in IDLE: http://pastebin.com/95ZNYkeE

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20828/discussion-between-lennart-regebro-and-mmgp)

Comment: I'm tired of hearing about how smart you are, I'm ignoring you on this discussion now. How do you know he actually runs the script in IDLE like you mention ? For instance, I would prefer something that works either in IDLE or some other shell, like the standard one and possibly non-standard-ones but that follow the standard use of user customize/sitecustomize. Now, really, I will no longer waste time with you.

Comment: You have been ignoring me the whole time. I also never talked bout me being smart, so you seem to be hearing things as well. How do I know he actually runs the script like this? 1. He implies it. 2. It's consistent with his description of what happens. If you had listened from the start, we would have been done with this two days ago, and you wouldn't have made yourself look like an idiot. I hope you learn this for next time.